How can I calculate DateDiff from one row column to the next row different column
I want to use DateDiff starting with row 1 column 2, row 2 column 1
CREATE TABLE Surgery 
(
    AccountNumber varchar(20),
    CaseNumber varchar(6),
    SurgDate DATETIME,
    ORRoom varchar(10),
    Surgeon varchar(50),
    InRoomTime TIME(3),
    OutRoomTime TIME(3)
)

INSERT INTO Surgery 
VALUES
('11111', '144995', '2024-07-19 00:00:00.000', 'OR06', 'SOK', '07:29', '08:30'),
('11111', '145017', '2024-07-19 00:00:00.000', 'OR06', 'SOK', '09:00', '10:18'),
('11111', '145028', '2024-07-19 00:00:00.000', 'OR06', 'SOK', '11:03', '13:00'),
('11111', '145027', '2024-07-19 00:00:00.000', 'OR06', 'SOK', '13:42', '16:20')

--SELECT * FROM Surgery

SELECT 
    InRoomTime,  
    (SELECT OutRoomTime
     FROM SURGERY AS table2
     WHERE table2.SurgDate = SurgDate AND table2.OutRoomTime < InRoomTime 
     --ORDER BY OutRoomTime DESC
    ) AS TOT
FROM SURGERY

What I would like to see is:
111411  144995  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 07:29:00.000    08:30:00.000 Time Difference mins
11111   145017  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 09:00:00.000    10:18:00.000 30
11111   145028  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 11:03:00.000    13:00:00.000 45
11111   145027  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 13:42:00.000    16:20:00.000 158


Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?

With SQL Server (2012+), I would use LAG:
SELECT AccountNumber, CaseNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom, Surgeon, InRoomTime, OutRoomTime, DATEDIFF(minute, PreviousPatientOutRoom, InRoomTime) AS MinuteDifference
FROM (
SELECT *, 
       LAG(OutRoomTime) OVER (ORDER BY InRoomTime) PreviousPatientOutRoom
FROM Surgery) A;

The output:
AccountNumber   CaseNumber  SurgDate    ORRoom  Surgeon InRoomTime  OutRoomTime MinuteDifference
11111   144995  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 07:29:00.000    08:30:00.000    NULL
11111   145017  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 09:00:00.000    10:18:00.000    30
11111   145028  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 11:03:00.000    13:00:00.000    45
11111   145027  2024-07-19 00:00:00.000 OR06    SOK 13:42:00.000    16:20:00.000    42

Following this method the time difference for the CaseNumber 145027 comes out as 42 and not 158 as in your example.

We can solve the problem in a simple way by making the input table into two separate alias.
Alias A will drop the first record, and a new column will be added as Serial ID named as RowNumber.
(SELECT distinct Row_Number() OVER (Order by AccountNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime ) AS RowNumber, AccountNumber, CaseNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime from surgery
WHERE  INROOMTIME > (SELECT MIN(INROOMTIME) FROM SURGERY)) 

Alias B will drop the last record, and a new column will be added as Serial ID named as RowNumber.
(SELECT distinct Row_Number() OVER (Order by AccountNumber,  SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime ) AS RowNumber, AccountNumber, CaseNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime,OUTROOMTIME from surgery
WHERE  INROOMTIME < (SELECT MAX(INROOMTIME) FROM SURGERY))

The solution
Finally, this two alias will be joined on column RowNumber and calculate the Minute Difference.
SELECT A.ROWNUMBER, A.AccountNumber, A.CaseNumber, A.SurgDate, A.ORRoom,
A.inroomtime, B.OUTROOMTIME, datediff(minute,B.OUTROOMTIME, A.inroomtime) as MinuteDiff FROM 
(SELECT distinct Row_Number() OVER (Order by AccountNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime ) AS RowNumber, AccountNumber, CaseNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime from surgery
WHERE  INROOMTIME > (SELECT MIN(INROOMTIME) FROM SURGERY))  a join 
(SELECT distinct Row_Number() OVER (Order by AccountNumber,  SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime ) AS RowNumber, AccountNumber, CaseNumber, SurgDate, ORRoom,
inroomtime,OUTROOMTIME from surgery
WHERE  INROOMTIME < (SELECT MAX(INROOMTIME) FROM SURGERY)) b on A.ROWNUMBER = B.ROWNUMBER

This will be the output
